# cat/echo command in du -sh --exclude={} command causing long runs and not functioning as expected

Tags: disk-usage

I'm an admirer of this page, i hope I find my answer here.

So, i wanted to check disk usage in particular file system for all directories excluding few directories(which i have in a file stored, gets created dynamically with some requirements).

But what i observed was when i hardcoded the values directly in exclude command, it was way fast and results were accurate. But when i was passing though commands inside exclude command. It was way more time consuming and yielded wrong results. I dont want to hardcode always, please suggest

Harcoded version (a, b are subdirectories) -- gave correct results

```
du -sh --exclude={a,b} filesystem/*
```

Command version

Assuming i have a file(directory_list.txt) with a and b directory names in it.

```
du -sh --exclude={`cat directory_list.txt`} /filesystem/*
```

Another thing which comes to my mind is as exclude is not yielding me accurate and timely results, i will select directories directly which i want

as below

```
ls filesystem/ | grep -v $(cat directory_list.txt) > selected.txt  --
```

excluding directories and selecting only needed

```
du -sh $(cat selected.txt)
```

But please suggest better way and how can i make my command in exclude command work 
Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: Please show the exact contents of `directory_list.txt`. The syntax is `--exclude=PATTERN`, so you must make sure that `{$(cat directory_list)}` results in a valid pattern.

Comment: Does your `du` version offer the 
      `-X, --exclude-from=FILE
                  exclude files that match any pattern in FILE`
option?

Comment: Assuming that `directory_list.txt` contains one directory per line, does `du -sh $(ls filesystem|fgrep -v -f directory_list.txt)` do what you want? Note that command substitution `$( ... )` has some pitfalls. It will not work if there are directory names that contain spaces or other special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `du` command on Linux, which seems to be what you are using, offers a `--exclude-from` option:

```
du -h -s --exclude-from=directory_list.txt /filesystem/*
```

or

```
du -h -s -X directory_list.txt /filesystem/*
```

This assumes that the file `directory_list.txt` contains shell globbing patterns (not regular expressions), one per line, that should be excluded.  These patterns may be pathnames, or just names of files or directories, and may include shell globbing characters.

---

In your command that uses `` --exclude={`cat directory_list.txt`} ``, you are trying to get the shell to do a brace expansion, using the contents of `directory_list.txt`.  This does not work as brace expansions are carried out *before* command substitutions are even considered.

What you *could* have done, if your `du` didn't have `--exclude-from`, is to read the things to exclude from your file into an array, and while doing so,  add `--exclude=` to every element, and then use that array in a call to `du`:

```bash
exclude=()
while IFS= read -r item; do
    exclude+=( --exclude="$item" )
done <directory_list.txt

du -h -s "${exclude[@]}" /filesystem/*
```

This assumes that, just like with `--exclude-from`, your file contains one pattern per line.

If you are using a shell that does not support arrays, you have the benefit of getting to type less:

```sh
set --
while IFS= read -r item; do
    set -- "$@" --exclude="$item"
done <directory_list.txt

du -h -s "$@" /filesystem/*
```

This uses the list of positional parameters instead of a named array.

Both of these loops would also preserve whitespace in pathnames, and would not allow the shell to erroneously expand filename globbing patterns, which is a couple of the issues with your `grep -v $(cat directory_list.txt)` command (another is that you'll pass most of the pathnames from the files to `grep` as files to search rather than as patterns to exclude).

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda for such great explanation, i was able to work fix the problem with -X command as you advised

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but sometimes people do convulsions with `du -sh` in efforts to find the disk hog.

If this is the case, you should consider the tool ncdu.  It is curses based and fast and will sort everything by total disk space consumed as you walk through the tree with arrow keys.